# Which is asymptotically larger $3n^{\sqrt{n}}$ or $2^{\sqrt{n}\log_{2} n}$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Which is asymptotically larger $3n^{\sqrt{n}}$ or $2^{\sqrt{n}\log_{2} n}$?

What I have done is taken $log$ on both sides, which gives

$$ f(n) =\log (3n)^{\sqrt n} $$ and $$ g(n) = \log (2)^{\sqrt n \log_2{n}}$$

This can be simplified to $ f(n) =\sqrt n \log (3n) $ and $ g(n) = {\sqrt n \log_2{n}}\log (2)$.

In order to determine the asymptotically larger function, we can plug in,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

How can this be simplified to determine the asymptotically larger function?

Comment: Comparing the asymptotic behavior of the ratio of logarithms is wrong. You need to look at the difference of the logarithms, or the direct ratio of the functions.

Comment: kinda think that the above comment is more valuable than all the answers so far. Why do people demand that questioners show their working, then totally ignore it?

Comment: So a comparison of the behavior of ratios can only be carried out when we're not taking log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$2^{\sqrt n\log_2n}=(2^{\log_2 n})^{\sqrt n}=n^{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: I understand the inverse of a logarithm is an exponential but can you explain the equality in an easier manner?

Comment: @kevin: I can't imagine anything simpler than $2^{\log_2(n)}$.

Comment: Oh I got it now actually, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both functions are of the form $Cn^{\sqrt n}$, hence are asymptotically equal.

Comment: Asymptotically within a constant factor.

Comment: In the $\Theta$ sense, equal.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your fraction, you can use the following basic facts about the logarithm:

1. $\log_2 n = \frac{\log n}{\log 2}$, and hence $g(n) = \sqrt{n} \log n$,
2. $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$, so $f(n) = \sqrt{n}(\log n + \log 3)$.

Cancel the $\sqrt n$ factors and you're almost there.

However, as a commenter on your post points out, the asymptotic behaviour of the logarithm of your function does not tell you the asymptotic behaviour of your function in general. Consider as an example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$. The logarithms of $f$ and $g$ differ by only a constant multiplicative factor, so asymptotically we consider them the same, but in contrast $g$ itself grows asymptotically faster than $f$.

For the right way forward, I refer you to any of the other answers.